# update content size of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have the following code:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *) scrollView
{
float currentEndPoint = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;

if (currentEndPoint >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
{
    UIView *parent = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 665.0, 310.0, 340.0)];
    parent.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    parent.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0;
    parent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor regularColor].CGColor;
    parent.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    // Increase size of content view
    CGRect newContentView = _contentView.frame;

    newContentView.size.width = _contentView.frame.size.width;
    newContentView.size.height = _contentView.frame.size.height + 340.0;

    [_contentView setFrame:newContentView];

    [_contentView addSubview:parent];
}
```

But so far the scroll view doesn't get it's updated content view.
**How do I update the content view here?**

Thanks.

Comment: is your design contains autoLayout Constraint?

Comment: scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size; I needed this.

Comment: @chris do you try change it the content size inside viewDidLayoutSubviews?